# Adding to a vector of pointers through a class function

Tags: c++, function, class, pointers, vector

Okay, I asked a similar question to this before somewhat recently, but I was tired and rushed when I posted it.  Basically, I have this parent class `Unit` that contains a vector of pointers to the `Ability` class.

```
public:
vector <Ability*>  myAbilities;
```

I also have a function built into the class to add a `new Ability` to make it easier to develop and add new skills for the `Unit`

```
void AddAbility(Ability * ability)
{
    myAbilities.push_back(ability);
    cout<<"Ability added"<<endl;
    cout<<ability->GetName()<<endl;
}
```

When I use it it looks like this:

```
AddAbility(new Fireball());
```

Now, my problem is when I test to see if the fireball information is still there, it doesn't show up unlike when the `AddAbility()` function is called.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Profession.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Player being a child class of Unit
    Player * player1 = new Mage;
    system("pause");

    player1->myAbilities[0]->GetName(); 
    system("pause");

    delete player1;
    player1 = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

My output looks like this:

> Ability Added
>
> Fireball
>
> Press any key to continue...
>
> Press any key to continue...

The name of the Ability appears to no longer be there, for it should have showed "Fireball" a second time after the first pause. I hope I explained this clearly and gave enough information because every time I try to research pointer parameters (or passing by pointer), it always shows me stuff about Function Pointers.

Comment: What's the constructor for `Mage`?

Comment: Your question misses to identify the sufficient parts of code that cause the problems.

Comment: It refuses to let me edit, so my constructor is:

    Mage::Mage()
 {
  myName = "---";
  myRoleName = "Mage";

  myRole = MAGE;

  myHealth = 100;
  myMana = 50;
  myDefense = 5;
  myDamage = 10;
  myMagicDamage = 10;
  myMagicDefense = 3;

  AddAbility(new Fireball());
 }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the GetName() function, it would appear that the function does not itself print the ability name to std::cout. This would mean that you would need to have `cout << player1->myAbilities[0]->GetName() << endl;`, not just `player1->myAbilities[0]->GetName();` in your main function.

Comment: Oh my gosh....I feel so stupid right now.... thank you >.<

Comment: @Uulamock It's no problem - all of us make silly mistakes from time to time. Just be sure to hit the check mark to the left of the answer if it helped!

Comment: @Invictus Thanks for reminding to hit the check mark, still slightly new to using stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I think your GetName function probably just returns the name. You then need to print the returned name.

If that's not it, then right after your first pause, check the size of the myAbilities vector. Should be 1. If it is 1, check the value of the pointer in myAbilities[0] to see if it's the same value that was passed into AddAbility. It should be.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to put `cout<<` before calling the function...I feel so stupid right now... and I did everything else you said too already before I posted this question... Thank you though. >.<